# How to write a python code to read data from ".bag" file and write data in bag file runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, bag

I have done following code to read data from .bag file

```
import os
f = open("/Volumes/aj/VLP16_Points_2017-10-24-11-21-21.bag", 'r')
print (f.read())
f.close()
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ajinkyabobade/PycharmProjects/storingfiles/storingimage.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (f.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 33: invalid start byte
```

How do I remove this error? Also how do I store data run time(as the bag file is being generated?)

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

```
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['chatter', 'numbers']):
   print(msg)
bag.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 `open()` uses your environment to choose an appropriate encoding. If you sure, that file encoded with utf-8 you could ignore invalid byte sequence with

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r', error='ignore') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Or you could chose right encoding (if your file is non utf-8 encoded) with

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r', encoding='needed_encoding') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Also, docs on `open` builtin could be [useful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: thank you, how do I find what type of encoding does my bag file have?

Comment: @Ajinkya Bobade If you using Linux try `file --mime filename`

Comment: I am using MacOS

Comment: I found out text/plain; charset=us-ascii . I modified the code to: 
 open("/Volumes/aj/VLP16_Points_2017-10-24-11-21-21.bag", 'r', encoding='us-ascii') as f:
. I am not sure why the error persists  the error I am getting is (UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
)

Comment: @Ajinkya Bobade Looks like your file is somehow corrupted. You could use `ignore` argument to read it anyway, or see how it was created and try to find problem there.

Comment: You might also try `latin-1` as the encoding - the lower half is the same as ascii, but it defines code points up to 0xFF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bagpy` package to read the .bag file in Python. It can be installed using pip

```
pip install bagpy
```

Brief documentation is at https://jmscslgroup.github.io/bagpy/

Following are example code-snippets:

```
import bagpy
from bagpy import bagreader

b = bagreader('09-23-59.bag')

# get the list of topics
print(b.topic_table)

# get all the messages of type velocity
velmsgs   = b.vel_data()
veldf = pd.read_csv(velmsgs[0])
plt.plot(veldf['Time'], veldf['linear.x'])

# quickly plot velocities
b.plot_vel(save_fig=True)

# you can animate a timeseries data
bagpy.animate_timeseries(veldf['Time'], veldf['linear.x'], title='Velocity Timeseries Plot')
```

However, it looks like the package is still under development.

Comment: How do you know that is `vel_data()` the correct method? By printing topic_table? If the topic is smth like `stringA/stringB` how does it work?