# Reading ROS bag file content directly with python

Tags: python, ros, bag

I want to extract topics of ros bag files directly with python without the need to install a full ros distribution on the machine. I'm currently using the "rosbag" package but afaik it requires a ROS installation and gets all topic/message definitions from that environment.
Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a python code to read data from ".bag" file and write data in bag file runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918566/how-to-write-a-python-code-to-read-data-from-bag-file-and-write-data-in-bag-f)

Answer (score 1):

No need of full ros for accessing the data from topic, But you actually need the Basic ROS. Because ROS topics have a ROS msgs type (msgs you are using in the topic must be installed) and to communicate with the topic ros master is required.

You can install the basic ROS not the full version. But then you might need to install the different package required for your appllication.

Comment: rosmaster should not be necessary when you read the bagfile directly using the rosbag API.